# Prove the right triangle identity: $\frac a A = \frac b B = \frac c C$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Prove the right triangle identity: $$\frac a A = \frac b B = \frac c C$$

this identity is stated in many books, but there is never given a proof of it. It allows one to multiply any side in a right triangle by a factor $k\in \mathbb R$ and then compute the other sides accordingly to get a scaled triangle with the same angle $\theta$.

[image]

Comment: You might want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem#Proof_of_the_theorem

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Are there no other way of proving it ? I don't like these geometric proofs.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Well, it's a theorem of geometry, so I don't know what you expect. You could always just assume it as an axiom I suppose.

Comment: It couldn't be proven by using $\sin$ or $\cos$ right? Because these rely on the result that should be proven ?

Comment: This is simply the *Fundamental Theorem of Similarity*.

Comment: The main issue here is that when you scale a space horizontally and vertically by the same factor, then every direction scales by the same factor, including all possible diagonals.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be ok with this?

Supose you have two triangles with sides a,b,c and A,B,C s.t. $ak=A, bk=B, ck=C$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$.
$$tan\theta=a/b$$
$$=1*a/b$$
$$=k/k*a/b$$
$$=ka/kb$$
$$=A/B$$

And 
$$A^2 +B^2 = C^2$$
$$(ak)^2 + (bk)^2 = (ck)^2$$
$$k^2(a^2+b^2)=k^2c^2$$
$$a^2 +b^2 = c^2$$

Comment: Good answer and of course "would you be okay with this" is the most important question: what does OP accept as axioms?  Where is bottom?